# Model defined function not recognized

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities

I have an ASP.NET 4.0 MVC project with a .edmx file, using Linq to Entities.  I added a function to the conceptual model, and I'm getting "not supported" errors.

EF Version:

```
<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net40" />
```

Here is the edmx part:

```
<edmx:ConceptualModels>
  <Schema Namespace="MillCertsModel" Alias="Self" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm" annotation:UseStrongSpatialTypes="false" xmlns:annotation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/annotation">
  ... EntityType elements ...
  <Function Name="IsLike" ReturnType="Edm.Boolean">
      <Parameter Name="str" Type="Edm.String" />
      <Parameter Name="pattern" Type="Edm.String" />
      <DefiningExpression>
        str LIKE pattern
      </DefiningExpression>
    </Function>
  </Schema>
</edmx:ConceptualModels>
```

and the function ...

```
public static class Utilities
{
    [System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EdmFunction("MillCertsModel", "IsLike")]
    public static bool IsLike(this string str, string pattern)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Supported for SQL queries only.");
    }
}
```

and the code ...

```
if (keywords != null)
   query = query.Where(m => keywords.Any(kw => m.CertificateData.Any(cd => cd.value.ToLower() == kw || cd.value.IsLike("[^a-z]"))));
```

**Error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsLike(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.  The namespace was wrong.

Correct namespace:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses

// NOT: System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EdmFunction
```

However, this attribute is now obsolete. `System.Data.Entity.DbFunctionAttribute` is recommended instead.

Comment: Damn! In documentation there is an old namespace - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.dataclasses.edmfunctionattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.6